# Get Workflow status Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, development

I am trying to get the workflow status from the list items in SP 2013 with c#. Unfortunatelly I cant get any values. I tried some pieces of code Ive found here. Here is what Im trying now:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("mysite"))
using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            var manager = site.WorkflowManager;
            var list = web.Lists["myList"];
            if (list == null || list.Hidden)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERR");
            }

            foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
            {
                foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in item.Workflows)
                {
                    if(workflow.InternalState == SPWorkflowState.Completed)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DONE");
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
```

There is a list "myList" in SP with 4 items and a set workflow "wflow" working everytime I add a new item to the list.

I would like to get the internal status for each item in the list.

Answer (score 3):

While Listing the workflows status for list items. You should be using WorkflowManager.

I have updated some part of your code. You can try with this:

```
// variable "item" is running under foreach loop when you iterate all list items 
    foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in manager.GetItemWorkflows(item))
    {
            if (workflow.ParentAssociation.Name == "wflow")
            {
                foreach (SPField field in workflow.ParentList.Fields)
                {
                    if (field is SPFieldWorkflowStatus)
                    {
                        SPFieldWorkflowStatus statusField = (SPFieldWorkflowStatus)field;
                        if (statusField.Title == "wflow")
                        {
                           int statusValue = int.Parse(item[statusField.StaticName].ToString());

                           // display the status however you want
                           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(statusField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(statusValue).ToString());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }                   
     }
```

Comment: Do let me know If you have queries!

Comment: Thanks for the code.

Unfortunatelly I didnt get nothing. I added: foreach(SPListItem item in list.items) and a bad debug way System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Workflows: " + item.Workflows.count); 

The answer was Workflows: 0. 

The code never goes in the foreach you sent. There is a column wflow for the workflow I created in the SP-Designer and the value "completed" is set when I check clicking on the item workflow in SP.

Comment: someone else with ideas why it does not go in the foreach in?